# request.getParameter is giving null even though button is clicked

Tags: jsp

I am using two submit buttons in one JSP page.
I need to use single form for both the buttons as the user input i am taking in the form is required for both the submit actions.
I used another JSP page in post action of form.
below is the code i tried:

first.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="Second.jsp">
<input type="submit" id="butn" class="button"  name=" Button1" value=" First Button "> 
<input type="submit" id="butn" class="button"  name=" Button2" value=" Second Button ">  
</form>
```

Second.jsp

```
if (request.getParameter("Button1") != null){
out.println("button1 is clicked");
}
else if (request.getParameter("Button2") != null){
out.println("button2 is clicked");
```

But in any case it is not giving any output.
As the value it is getting is null only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possibly because you have a space in the 'name' of your input?

```
 <input type="submit" id="butn" class="button"  name=" Button1" value=" First Button ">
```

instead of

```
 <input type="submit" id="butn" class="button"  name="Button1" value=" First Button ">
```

Comment: Ohhh!!!
Thank you so much..
I wasted my half day investigating the issue.
I removed the space now and yes it is working. :)

Comment: @shilpa You are welcome, you can accept this as the correct answers to let other people know :-)

Comment: Also now i have one more question.
What if i want to call other jsp page on click of it.
So what we can use in If statement instead of just print statement.